# getting error notifydatasetchanged() when search data from searchview

Tags: android

**I have fragment like below image with searchview in actionbar**

**I search on it and got some link also and try it but its not work**

I want to search data from below listview.

**I have done code for it but it give error like this**

```
                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131558596, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter
```

I have write notifydatasetchanged() that in getview still get this error don`t know  where i did mistake please help me.

**Thank you in advance**

[image: Fragment which have searchview in actionbar]

**My CustomAdapter code is below**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

ArrayList<D> dList;
LayoutInflater inflater;

Context context;

private int lastPosition = 0;
ArrayList<D> tempList;
ArrayList<D> reloadList;
private DFilter dFilter;
D dModel;

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<D> myList, ArrayList<D> allDList) {
    this.dList = myList;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    this.tempList = new ArrayList<D>();
    this.tempList.addAll(allDList);
    getFilter();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return dList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return dList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    MyViewHolder mViewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_d_list, parent, false);
        mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    } else {
        mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    try {
        dModel = dList.get(position);
        mViewHolder.tvName.setText(dModel.getDName());
        mViewHolder.tvDegree.setText(dModel.getDEducation());
        mViewHolder.ivImage.setImageResource(dModel.getDImageNumber());
       notifyDataSetChanged();

        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
        convertView.startAnimation(animation);
    lastPosition = position;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return convertView;


}


private class MyViewHolder {
    TextView tvName, tvDegree;
    ImageView ivImage;

    public MyViewHolder(View item) {

        tvName = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.custom_d_list_tv_name);
        tvDegree = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.custom_d_list_tv_degree);
        ivImage = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.custom_d_list_iv);
    }
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (dFilter == null) {
        dFilter = new DFilter();
    }
    return dFilter;

}

private class DFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        final String searchString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
        Log.i("TAG", "Query=>" + constraint);
        final FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint != null && constraint.toString()!="") {
            dList.clear();

            for (D d : tempList) {
                if (d.getDName().toLowerCase().contains(searchString)) {
                    dList.add(d);
                    Log.i("TAG", "SEARCH DATA=>" + tempList);
                }
            }
            filterResults.count = dList.size();
            Log.i("TAG", "FilterResultCount=>" + filterResults.count);
            filterResults.values = dList;
            Log.i("TAG", "FilterResultValues=>" + filterResults.values);

        } else {

            filterResults.count = dList.size();
            filterResults.values = dList;

        }
        return filterResults;

    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {


        dList = (ArrayList<D>) results.values;

        notifyDataSetChanged();

        Log.i("TAG", "SearchResult" + dList);


    }
 } }
```

Comment: do you want to add search functionality for listview

Comment: Why do you call `notifyDataSetChanged();` in `getView()`? You want to get infinite loop?

Comment: @DamianKozlak Its not work same error shown

Comment: @VishalHalani how about my solution below (answer)?

Comment: @DamianKozlak I try it but its not solve my error same error

Comment: @DamianKozlak Dear Not working that solution also :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved it thanks to all for response.** 
*I change below Logic in my fragment and its solve*

```
  private void loadA() {


    for (D tempD : arrayA) {
        dList.add(tempD);

    }
    setAdapter(dList,allDList);

}
private void loadB() {

    for (D tempD : arrayB) {
        dList.add(tempD);

    }
    setAdapter(dList,allDList);

    Log.i("ListSize", "" + dList.size());}
private void setAdapter(ArrayList<D> dList,ArrayList<D> allDList)
{
    adapter=new CustomDoctorsListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),dList,allDList);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    lvDoctors.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvDoctors.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}

  @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (newText.equals("")) {

                if (A.isChecked() == true) {

                    // lv.clearTextFilter();
                    adapter.dList.clear();
                    loadA();

                } else {

                    //lv.clearTextFilter();
                    adapter.dList.clear();

                  loadB();
                }


            }else {


                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            }


            return true;
        }
```